# How to open php files through localhost?

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache, xampp

I am a high schooler who wants to learn how to code.
I am developing a student management program with xampp, php, mySQL, and Apache.
When I opened my index.html file with localhost: *localhost/superschool/index.html*, the site address changed into *localhost/superschool/index.php*. This shows up this error messages:
**HTTP ERROR 500** with console message: **(index):7290 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.**
I'm not sure why this happened.
Would you please give me an insight to solve this problem?
Thank you so much! Here's my index.html and index.php files for the references.

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=index.php">
        <title>Loading ...</title>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

**index.php**

```
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
    $currDir = dirname(__FILE__);
    include("{$currDir}/defaultLang.php");
    include("{$currDir}/language.php");
    include("{$currDir}/lib.php");

    $x = new DataList;
    $x->TableTitle = $Translation['homepage'];
    $tablesPerRow = 2;
    $arrTables = getTableList();

    // according to provided GET parameters, either log out, show login form (possibly with a failed login message), or show homepage
    if(isset($_GET['signOut'])){
        logOutUser();
        redirect("index.php?signIn=1");
    }elseif(isset($_GET['loginFailed']) || isset($_GET['signIn'])){
        if(!headers_sent() && isset($_GET['loginFailed'])) header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
        include("{$currDir}/login.php");
    }else{
        include("{$currDir}/main.php");
    }
```

Comment: Point 1: If the file contains PHP script it cannot have a `.html` extension, it should have a `.php` extension. The `.php` extension tells Apache to pass the code to the PHP interpreter for compilation and execution.

Comment: Your `.php` file should start with `<?php`. The rest seems ok

Comment: @RiggsFolly The `index.html` file doesn't contain any PHP

Comment: So why have a `index.html` at all? Apache shoudl be setup to launch a `index.php` by default and if not you can look ui how to set that up

Comment: you should just delete the `index.html` file and not directly call `index.html` in your links etc

Comment: "_with console message_" and `non-JS module files deprecated` sound like there's something wrong with some Javascript - which we don't see.

Comment: I tried all of them, but it still doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command
First, you'll need to install PHP

> pkg install php

> pkg upgrade php

> Pkg update php

Make sure you upgrade and update it!

Move over the directory were your php file is located and type this commands

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

You could change the port to your own choice...